# Swapping two integers using pointers using c

Tags: c, pointers, reference

I am trying to swap the value of two integers using pointers, see code below: swapping number using pointer in c:

```
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;

    swapr(&a, &b);
    printf("a=%d\n", a);
    printf("b=%d\n", b);
    return 0;
}

void swapr(int *x, int *y)  //function
{
    int t;
    t=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=t;
}
```

In the code why is `swap(&A, &B);` used when `*x` and `*y` point to a value not an address

Comment: you have to read about passing by reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say `(int *x, int *y)` you're just declaring `x` and `y` as pointers. In all future usages, when you say `x`, it means the pointer and when you say `*x`, it means the value it points to.

Answer (score 3):

In a declaration, the `*` in the declarator indicates that the object has pointer type.  Take the declaration

```
int *p;
```

The type of `p` is "pointer to `int`".  This type is specified by the combination of the type specifier `int` and the *declarator* `*p`.

Pointer-ness, array-ness, and function-ness are all specified as part of the declarator:

```
T *p;       // p is a pointer to T
T a[N];     // a is an N-element array of T
T f();      // f is a function returning T
T *ap[N];   // ap is an array of pointers to T
T (*pa)[N]; // pa is a pointer to an array of T
T *fp();    // fp is a function returning pointer to T
T (*pf)();  // pf is a pointer to a function returning T
```

etc.

In C, declaration mimics use - if you have a pointer to an `int` named `p` and you want to access the value it points to, you dereference it with the `*` operator, like so:

```
x = *p;
```

The *expression* `*p` has type `int`, so the *declaration* of `p` is

```
int *p;
```

In `main`, the expressions `&a` and `&b` have type `int *`, so the corresponding parameters have to be declared as `int *`.

```
 x == &a // int * == int *
 y == &b // int * == int *

*x ==  a // int == int
*y ==  b // int == int
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the way var declarations work is if you declare a variable

```
int c;
```

You've just declared an integer and you can assign values to it or retrieve its value like this

```
int a;
int b;
a = 10;  // assign 10
b = a;   //assign value of a to b
```

Pointers are a bit different though. If you declare a pointer and you want to assign a value to it then you must dereference it with the * operator

```
int * a;  // declare a pointer
int b;    // declare a var
b = 10;   // assign 10 to b
*a = b;   // assign 10 as the value of a
b = 20;   // b is now 20 but the var a remains 10
```

But you can also assign a pointer to point at a memory address

```
int * a;
int b;
b = 10;   // assign 10 to b
a = &b;   // assign address of b to a (a points at b)
b = 20;   // value of b changes (thus value of a is also 20 since it is pointing at b
```

So if you have a function signature

```
int func (int * a, int * b);
```

All this is means is that the function takes the address of two variable

```
int a;
int b;
int * x;
int * y;

func(&a, &b); // send it the address of a and b
func(x, y);   // send it the address of x and y
func(x, &b);
```

Basically a normal var's address can be accessed with the & operator.